# Process Substitution (e. g. $(somecommand) ) In A Nutshell

Tags: linux, shell, process-substitution, eval

On my shell from home directory on mac, I  run the following 
`eval "ls"` and this just shows me the directories. But if I run

`eval "$(ls)"` I get the following output:

```
    zsh: command not found: Applications
zsh: command not found: Desktop
zsh: command not found: Development
zsh: command not found: Development.zip
zsh: command not found: Documents
zsh: command not found: Downloads
zsh: command not found: Dropbox
zsh: command not found: Library
zsh: command not found: Movies
zsh: command not found: Music
zsh: command not found: Pictures
zsh: command not found: Public
```

i am not clear what is happening here. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct `$(stuff)` will replace itself with the results of running `stuff` in a subshell.  So:

```
echo $(echo hello)
```

will become

```
echo hello
```

Therefore,

```
eval "$(ls)"
```

will run `ls`, take its output, and use that output as the argument for `eval`.

Comment: excellent. and what would eval try to do ? this is also part of my confusion.  can you show a simple example of what eval is used for ?

Comment: Most of the time, `eval` is used unnecessarily.  For example, one common use of `eval` is to obtain the value of a variable, where the name _of_ the variable is not known until runtime.  `bash` allows for `${!variable}` indirection, though, so `eval` isn't needed.  It's sometimes still useful for constructing longer commands containing operators, reserved words, and so on, but it is a tool which is subtle and quick to anger.

Comment: im still lost. i first saw it on this command for docker:   eval "$(docker-machine env default)" and i was wondering why not simply do: docker-machine env default ... maybe i'll keep researching its use.

Comment: As you inferred, `eval` takes a string as its argument, and evaluates it as if you'd typed that string on a command line (multiple arguments are joined with spaces between them to what is "typed").  I don't know why `eval` would be needed in the context which you have described.

Comment: @j2emanue: one of the few places shell `eval` is needed is to execute commands generated by a program to set variable(s) (env vars or shell vars) in the shell. Your comment is such a case, and if you want to know about it, you might ask a question -- but it's already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038572/eval-docker-machine-env-default